# Plot a graph using data from database

Tags: c#, mysql

I have database stored in MYSQL and I want to extract values from one table that are relevant to me and plot them on a graph. I want to use chart control in c# (can be found in toolbox under the data). I know that I must first read the data from table but I have to plot that data on the graph.

For example I have something like this table:

Columns: id, name, value, timestamp.

I have another table which defines offsets for particular names of variables. I want to plot values for specific names using that control chart.

I started coding but I have never used the chart control and I dont know how to bind database with that (to use lists, datasets or datatables?). Here is the code:

```
            OdbcDataAdapter dAdapter1 = new OdbcDataAdapter(query1, connection);
            DataTable dTable1 = new DataTable();
            dAdapter1.Fill(dTable1);


            OdbcDataAdapter dAdapter2 = new OdbcDataAdapter(query2, connection);
            DataTable dTable2 = new DataTable();
            dAdapter2.Fill(dTable2);


            chartVariable.DataSource = bSource1;

            chartVariable.Titles.Add("Varibale Graph");
            int index = dTable1.Columns[2];
            for (int i = 0; i < dTable1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                chartVariable.Series[dTable1.Columns[0].ColumnName].Points[index];
            }
```

Comment: What charts are you using? With the win forms visualisation charts you can either bind to a data source or manually plot the points, you dont need to do both.  Try the below link, that samples especially helped me learn how to use the chart controls. Good luck.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/hr/MSWinWebChart/thread/0729d42d-1873-4f0d-88f6-3495634a50aa

Comment: Thanks for this. I gona look in this stuff now.